# How do you spot enemies in Gears of War 3?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I've noticed during multiplayer matches that enemies can be spotted, which makes a mark appears above them in the display. I've found this really useful for targeting and tracking enemies because the mark appears for a few seconds, even when they go behind cover.

However, I can't work out how to do it. How do you spot enemies in Gears of War 3?

Comment: They're the ones shooting at you. :P

Comment: @Blake except for the ones waiting behind a corner with a sawn off shotgun.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While looking at an enemy, hold down the left trigger button (as if to aim your weapon) and click down the left stick. Your character should then say something along the lines of "enemy spotted" and a symbol will appear over the enemy's head.

---

Additional information:

- Spotting an enemy in Horde mode will earn you a little cash if that enemy is subsequently killed.
- If you are killed in Horde mode, you can still spot enemies for your team mates by entering ghost mode by pressing `X` (which enables you to float around the map) and then clicking the left stick to spot enemies. This enables you to earn cash to use in the next round, or to buy yourself back into the round if you earn enough.
- Weapons and ammo can also be spotted using the same technique; if you spot 3 weapons that are subsequently picked up by team mates, you will earn the *Reconnaissance* ribbon.
- You can earn the *Military Intelligence* ribbon by spotting 5 enemies that are subsequently killed.
- Spotting enough enemies will earn you the *Spotter* medal.

Comment: I always forget that the sticks can be used as buttons too, thanks.

Comment: You can also spot items by doing the same thing (note that you need to be within almost 2m/6ft of the item to mark it.

Comment: @CyberSkull Like ammo or weapons? I've not seen that in a match yet, but definitely have to try that later.

Comment: @jaminja Spotting ammo/weapons can be done in any mode, you just have to be in arms reach of the stuff.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in Horde, when you are dead, press X to activate the ghost camera. You can then click LS to spot enemies, ammo & weapons.